# Arduino w/ PWM expander and DC motor issue

Tags: arduino, dc-motor

I am new to the forum. so.. Hi everyone

I am trying to control several DC 3-5v motor/pump with Arduino, using PCA9685 PWM expander.
I have connected one such motor, with a rectifying diode (IN4007), to 5V using a BC547 transistor, 2.2K resistor, the PCA9685 module, Arduino Due and 3.3V and 5V sources (with common ground). as in the diagram below.

The program on it runs a sweep on 0-100% and back on port 0.

Now..
IF I do NOT connect the motor, but instead put some random resistor load, everything works fine. I can measure across the load resistor a voltage going up from 0 to 5 and back down. All works 100% fine.

HOWEVER..

IF instead, I connected the motor where it should be, the program goes crazy as soon as the load across the motor gets to about 2-3 volts (or about 1.5V on the port 0 PWM).
The PWM stops updating and the serial console debugging clearly shows that something drags down the Arduino (the console stats updating slowly instead of the regular speed), due to I2C communication issues apparently (which hints that the PWM expander module went crazy). The Arduino can't seem to communicate with it anymore.
Disconnecting the motor at this stage doesn't help. Even then, the PWM doesn't update. The voltage on the 0 port remains stuck at the same level.. same for the motor. Things just get stuck.
Resetting the Arduino doesn't help.
If I disconnect the PWM module, the console logging goes back to regular speed (again, hinting that the PWM module went "crazy" and it is what is causing the console log drag).
Also, plugging the PWM module back in, doesn't solve the issue right away all the time, even at the beginning. It sometimes needs to "rest" for a bit. Then, once plugged in again it resumes working again like before.. meaning, only for the first second or so, until it goes crazy again.

I have no idea what is going on.
At first, I thought it has to do with a voltage created by the engine.. so I've added the rectifying diode. But that didn't help. Same issue.
I've also added a diode on the base, thinking maybe for some reason there is a current trying to flow back into the PWM module through the (orange) PWM port. But that also didn't help.

Why would the PWM module go crazy like that?
What causes it?
How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using the arduino's 5V to supply the motor? How much current does this motor is expected to draw?

Comment: adruinonerd2 - Hi, You said: "*... as in the diagram below*" but you didn't include the diagram in your posting! Please edit your question to include that. Also, I suspect that some photos of the hardware will also help people to see things like lengths of wire & exactly where you connected the diode you mentioned etc. So if you have got some photos, please add a couple when you edit the question (photos must be suitably downscaled & cropped for viewing on a monitor, also max size 2MB). Thanks.

Comment: A common problem. *going crazy that only a power-down followed by a power-up fixes*....this is most likely a **latch-up** problem, where transients caused by PWM motor switching feed back into Arduino's control lines. Transients exceed logic levels, either extending below GND or above VDD. While chips take internal precautions against latch-up, you can still invoke latch-up that only resolves with a power-down. Sometimes adding bypass capacitors between VDD-to-GND help. May require re-routing GND lines back to supply.

Comment: adruinonerd2 - It seems you asked the same question on the [EEVblog forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/arduino-w-pwm-expander-and-dc-motor-issue/) and on [Eleco-Tech-Online.com](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/arduino-w-pwm-expander-and-dc-motor-issue.160160/), both of which gave good advice, but replies from you stopped. Starting *from scratch* again here, after so much work has been done already seems strange! What advice did you get after posting on [Freelancer](https://www.freelancer.com/projects/arduino/electronics-advisory-arduino-pwm/?ngsw-bypass=&w=f)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it omits the lessons of the asker's lengthy previous pursuit of this question in other places on the Internet.  This sort of "answer shopping" is not how problems are solved; why should people here invest time in this if you are only going to ignore the responses here as you have those elsewhere?  Probably you have an issue with an insufficient power supply for the motor load and or the insufficiency of the BC547 as a switch, but why start over from scratch with no history of previous inquiries?